# Firefox for Raspi

Tags: web-browsers, firefox

I have a personal preference for FF - mainly because I use it on the Mac's I have
But in my ignorance I am unsure whether it is "safe" to install on Pi4 under Raspi.

Comment: You should probably put your RPi in a Faraday cage and do not connect anything if you want to be "safe".

Comment: Pretty sure the dark army can still do things via quantum entanglement there.  To be safe you have to disconnect it from any power source.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox is better than any other browser, Even Chromium is a processing hog for Raspbian. You can use FF if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Dunno why you would think it might not be safe on the Pi if it is safe on the Mac.  Anyway, it's in the normal repositories -- try:

```
apt search firefox
```

I think the thing you want is `firefox-esr` (but see below).  Anything in the repo can be considered as "reasonably safe":  Obviously any and all software is susceptible to bugs and security issues; Debian, which is the foundation of Raspbian/RpiOS, is very good at identifying and dealing with the latter.

WRT firefox, there's [a bit of a weird history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_software_rebranded_by_Debian) within Debian derived distros.
Basically, there is/was a version of firefox called "iceweasel" that was used to circumvent some copyright issues.  It's still in *buster* as "[a transitional package](https://packages.debian.org/buster/iceweasel) which can be safely removed".  I just mention this because you may see it referred to elsewhere particularly in older information.

Comment: I had read about Iceweasel BUT where I came across the notion that FF was an issue I cannot remember! And yes, I know nothing is 100% safe